# Setup Spring app on the deploy

Tags: spring, security, deployment, spring-security, web-deployment

Is this a good practice to use CommandLineRunner to setup app on the first deploy. For example, I want to:

1. Create user's roles in the DB;
2. Load admin's login and pass from property file and create admin-user (on user per app) in the DB.

Or can you advise a better variant for me?

Answer (score 0):

I would not recommend doing it that way. Database setup, as well as future migrations, are handled nicely with either [Flyway](https://flywaydb.org/) or [Liquibase](http://www.liquibase.org/).